# How to create a client program for spring websocket server?

Tags: java, stomp, spring-websocket

HI i am trying to test scalability test for spring websocket server. I have created a spring websocket server that will receive an name and send back a greeting message to client. But i want to create a client program to test this server. I have no idea how to do it . I have researched on web and found that gozirra or stompj libraries are used for creating client. But i didn't get its maven dependency. Please help me.

Comment: Why don't use Spring's `WebSocketClient` stuff ?

Comment: Thnaks for answering. Do you have any example for java using WebSocketClient . Please forward me a link

Comment: You can take a look to test-cases: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/socket and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/websocket/client

Comment: Please can you add a class which can test this spring websocket ?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear. The `WebSocketConnectionManager` is for you